# SUMIFS corrupting spreadsheets with PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am using PHPSpreadsheet and am reading in a spreadsheet with the following (working correctly) formula. I'm using Libre Office to generate my spreadsheet.

`=SUMIFS($My_sheet.C:C,$My_sheet.B:B,">"&$'Home page'.$I$12,$My_sheet.B:B,"<"&$'Home page'.$I$13)`

For some reason when I remove the offending rows my sheet reads/writes perfectly fine but with them I get corrupted files and it throws unreadable files.

I'm not setting the value - this is already in the spreadsheet I'm reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help someone. I was looking for `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Statistical\Conditional::SUMIFS()` as your call.

For the example given simply wrap each `,` separated section in quotes and pass them to this function. So the answer would be:

`use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Statistical\Conditional as StatCond;`

`StatCond::SUMIFS('$My_sheet.C:C','$My_sheet.B:B','">"&$\'Home page\'.$I$12','My_sheet.B:B','"<"&$\'Home page\'.$I$13')`